# Causing Deadlock situation when implementing Runnable interface and running fine when extending Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

For understanding of wait() and notifyAll() functionality, I was creating a program to get better at the mentioned concept of multithreading. But somehow, I noticed that the following program runs fine when working via Thread class and producing the expected output. But when I switched the same program with Runnable interface, I am facing with deadlock problem.

Any suggestions where I am going wrong or what understanding I am lacking about the concept.

```
class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
    new Waiter(notifier, "A").start();
    new Waiter(notifier, "B").start();

    notifier.start();
  }
}
```

Waiter class to invoke wait() on different threads.

```
class Waiter extends Thread{

  private Notifier notifier;

  Waiter(Notifier notifier, String name){
    super(name);
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized(notifier){
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to call wait()");
      try{
        notifier.wait();
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will now continue with remaining code");
    }
  }
}
```

Notifier class to invoke notifyAll() and notify all the waiting threads.

```
class Notifier extends Thread{
  public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
      try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        System.out.println("Notifying all threads");
        notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

O/P of the following program is

```
A is trying to call wait()
B is trying to call wait()
Notifying all threads
B will now continue with remaining code
A will now continue with remaining code
```

Now the same program using Runnable Interface

```
class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
    // new Waiter(notifier, "A").start();
    // new Waiter(notifier, "B").start();
    //
    // notifier.start();

    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "A").start();
    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "B").start();
   
    new Thread(notifier).start();
  }
}

class Waiter implements Runnable{

  private Notifier notifier;

  Waiter(Notifier notifier){
    // super(name);
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized(notifier){
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to call wait()");
      try{
        notifier.wait();
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will now continue with remaining code");

    }
  }
}

class Notifier implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
      try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        System.out.println("Notifying all threads");
        notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

O/P of the following program and causing deadlock situation

```
A is trying to call wait()
Notifying all threads
B is trying to call wait()
A will now continue with remaining code
```

I have tried to start the Notifier thread after 1 millisecond by causing the main thread to sleep for 1ms and getting the desired output.

```
    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "A").start();
    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "B").start();

     try{
       Thread.sleep(1);
     }catch(InterruptedException e){}

    new Thread(notifier).start();
```

But why it's not working when starting Notifier thread normally/sequentially(ie without sleeping). Is it because I am creating extra object for Runnable purpose or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a typical race condition problem. Both of your examples are similar. If `Thread` with the name `Notifier` will faster than thread `A` or `B` you will get `DeadLock` for code with usage `Thread` extending and code with `Runnable` implementation.

And if your `Notifier` will be last your code will succeed for both examples.
You can just run your code a lot of times and reproduce all of them situation.

You have a lot of types of solutions for this problem, I've written one of them with two CountDownLatch. In this example, we'll have a strictly defined sequence of threads execution:

```
 public class Solution0 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
        new Waiter(countDownLatch1, "A").start();
        while (countDownLatch1.getCount() != 0) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        new Waiter(countDownLatch2, "B").start();
        while (countDownLatch2.getCount() != 0) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
        notifier.start();
    }
}

class Waiter extends Thread {

    private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    Waiter(CountDownLatch countDownLatch, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to call wait()");
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}

class Notifier extends Thread {

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Notifying all threads");
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what might be the solution in order to avoid the race condition because I am using synchronized block in method and still not getting the desired output

Comment: You didn't ask about the solution problem, You asked "Why", however, I edited my answer and added the solution's example

Comment: thank you for correcting me and providing the solution...Have a good day!!!

Comment: I am not that much aware of CountDownLatch Class. Though you have provided the solution but it is not clearing my doubt(because I want to get better understanding of wait() and notifyAll()) as their is no wait() in your provided solution which is performing operation on CountDownLatch object and not on Notifier object. I want that changes should made in my program in such a way that it still operate on Notifier object rather that any other. Can I start the Notifier thread after some milliseconds to get the appropriate output(already described in the last section of my question)?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the reason behind not getting the desired output. It was because I am doing operation on notifier object. Now, when we start several threads in our program, they executes randomly and not in sequence because Thread Scheduler(part of the JVM) decides which thread should run at that moment and it is not gauranteed in which order the threads will run.

In addition, each object has a unique lock with it. The thread should be the owner of that object while calling wait(), notify() and notifyAll() on any object ie the thread must has lock of that object. Now, when a thread(Waiter thread in our case) calls wait() on some object(Notifier is the object in our case),

```
  class Waiter implements Runnable{

  private Notifier notifier;

  Waiter(Notifier notifier){
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized(notifier){
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to call wait()");
      try{
        notifier.wait();
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will now continue with remaining code");

    }
  }
}
```

then that thread releases the lock immediately and goes into waiting state so that other threads can work on that object. Now, suppose the Notifier thread got the chance to run(given by the Thread Scheduler) and it got the lock.

```
class Notifier implements Runnable{
  public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
      try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        System.out.println("Notifying all threads");
        notifyAll();
    }
  }
```

Now, after finishing it's task, it(Notifier thread) notifies all the threads(by calling notifyAll()) and releases the lock so that other threads(Waiter threads) can continue their further execution. When other Waiter threads starts their execution, they enter into synchronized block and call wait() and they have to wait lifelong(or until we exit from the program abnormally) as no one is there to notify them because Notifier thread has already been executed and which causes the deadlock situation.

Now, this problem can be resolved if we start the Notifier thread after some time(millisecond), so that all the threads(Waiter threads) can start their execution one by one to call wait() on Notifier object even before Notifier Thread is started and desired output will be produced.

```
  new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "A").start();
  new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "B").start();

   try{
     Thread.sleep(1);
   }catch(InterruptedException e){}

  new Thread(notifier).start();
```

Following is the fixed program

```
class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Notifier notifier = new Notifier();
    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "A").start();
    new Thread(new Waiter(notifier), "B").start();

    try{
      Thread.sleep(1);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}

    new Thread(notifier, "Notifier").start();
  }
}

class Waiter implements Runnable{

  private Notifier notifier;

  Waiter(Notifier notifier){
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized(notifier){
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to call wait()");
      try{
        notifier.wait();
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will now continue with remaining code");
      }
    }
  }

  class Notifier implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
      synchronized(this){
        try{
          Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){}
          System.out.println("Notifying all threads");
          notifyAll();
        }
      }
    }
```

And the desired output:

```
A is trying to call wait()
B is trying to call wait()
Notifying all threads
B will now continue with remaining code
A will now continue with remaining code
```